# Apache Kafka Connect Task Restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka Connect. I am writing a script which detects kafka connect failed tasks and restarts them. But the restart api which apache kafka has provided doesn't say if the task is actually restarted or not, we just know that the restart command was successfully sent.

I want a response if the task was successfully restarted/not. I could put a wait condition and check the task health after the restart command was issued, but the health api also has a delay in reflecting the actual status.

How can I achieve this. Is there a way to synchronously restart the connector tasks?

Answer (score 0):

There is two restart endpoints, by the way - `connector/restart` and `task-id/restart`.

But, in my experience, polling for the health is the best you can do, with a retry-limit on whatever process is sending the restart event.